# Kubernetes ingress: could not connect?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Traffic flow to implement:

```
client ---> Ingress (SSL,LoadBalancer) --> my_web(service) -> PODs
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx

  rules:
    - host: "test.foo.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: my_web
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Could not connect ingress port 80:

```
curl http://test.foo.com:80      <--- could not connect
```

test.foo.com is mapped to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file.

Could connect to the my_web service (loadBalancer) directly

```
curl http://localhost:8080    <---- success
```

Does ingress expose any port externally?

my_web_service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my_web
  labels:
    app: my_web
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: my_web
  type: LoadBalancer
```

my_web_deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my_web
  labels:
    app: my_web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my_web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my_web
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: my_web:latest
          name: my_web
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

Comment: Have you set up an ingress controller? I think when you call "localhost:8080" you are hitting the container directly without going through Kubernetes. But I am not sure, can you provide more information about the configuration?

Comment: localhost:8080 is going to the my_web service directly without going through ingress.

Comment: The service my_web should be internal to the cluster, and the ingress needs to be the frontend.

Comment: `nslookup` resolves to the same IP of your load balancer?

Comment: test.foo.com is resolved to localhost.

Comment: K8s by default does not provide a load balancer service, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer in on-premise cluster you have to use something like metallb

Answer (score 1):

Ingress itself does not expose ports if you don't configure a loadbalancer service for the ingress implementation.

Use

curl http://test.foo.com:8080

in your case

Comment: the my_web service is configured as a load balancer. but we need the ingress in the frontend.

Comment: Create a Service of type LoadBalancer for your ingress controller.

Comment: The my_web service in the example is of type LoadBalancer.  How many such LoadBalancer instances are running in the cluster? If there is one only, an external load balancer such as Nginx is meaningful? thanks.

Comment: http://test.foo.com:8080 bypass ingress, going to the my_web service directly, which does not support SSL.

Comment: Please stay on topic and open a separate question if you need a different approach.

Comment: It is on topic. The reason for this is to use SSL in the real app. So need to use ingress instead of accessing the service directly.

Answer (score 0):

I install ingressController with helm
Edit    hostNetwork: true

⋊> ubuntu@server71 ⋊> ~/h/i/helm-ingress kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx-2024 -owide                                        10:05:11
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/nginx-ingress-controller-59d5b69746-trf5b   1/1     Running   0          4s    103.143.207.51   server51

NAME                               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE   SELECTOR
service/nginx-ingress-controller   LoadBalancer   10.233.3.164        80:32320/TCP,443:30437/TCP   15h   app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress,app.kubernetes.io/name=nginx-ingress

NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS      IMAGES                      SELECTOR
deployment.apps/nginx-ingress-controller   1/1     1            1           15h   nginx-ingress   nginx/nginx-ingress:3.4.3   app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress,app.kubernetes.io/name=nginx-ingress

NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE     CONTAINERS      IMAGES                      SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/nginx-ingress-controller-59d5b69746   1         1         1       15h     nginx-ingress   nginx/nginx-ingress:3.4.3   app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress,app.kubernetes.io/name=nginx-ingress,pod-template-hash=59d5b69746
replicaset.apps/nginx-ingress-controller-5d6fd69877   0         0         0       7h58m   nginx-ingress   nginx/nginx-ingress:3.4.3   app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress,app.kubernetes.io/name=nginx-ingress,pod-template-hash=5d6fd69877
replicaset.apps/nginx-ingress-controller-649cd64c4f   0         0         0       15h     nginx-ingress   nginx/nginx-ingress:3.4.3   app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress,app.kubernetes.io/name=nginx-ingress,pod-template-hash=649cd64c4f

But If you have used helm and still have the problem, you can try editing HostNetwork and upgrade helm, then delete the pod to deploy and recreate the pord, and now
Use

curl http://test.foo.com

in your case